# Vimeo search videos "app not allowed to perform that action"

Tags: api, video, feed, vimeo, vimeo-api

Man it seems improbably difficult just to get a URL that searches Vimeo videos. They've got feed URLs to get specific users' videos, or info on a specific video, but seemingly not for a generic video search.

From other posts and the docs, I eventually came up with this:

```
https://api.vimeo.com/videos?query=vimeo&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

...where client_id is valid (having registered my app).

However that yields an error that...

```
the app is not allowed to perform that action.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The current API docs are more of a spec than user docs. We are finalizing the docs now, and that should make feature discovery much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - All API Apps now have access to the beta API by default. If you encounter this error it's a different issue, and you should contact Vimeo at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

It looks like you are trying to use API3.

Currently API3 is in beta, and has to be explicitly enabled by going to the url to edit your app : "developer.vimeo.com/apps/:id/edit" and add the querystring "?oauth2=enabled".

Your final URL should look like "developer.vimeo.com/apps/:id/edit?oauth2=enabled". Now save your app again with the new "OAuth 2" check box clicked and try your search request again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. All a bit bemusing; I just wanted a feed, a la YouTube, to search vids - not have to tackle oAuth or anything :)

Comment: You won't have to go through the oauth process to make unauthenticated requests like your search request. Your above url should work just fine, you just need to opt in to api3.

Comment: How do I opt in? I went to my app settings and I see no such option - it asks just basic stuff like app name, logo URL, callback URL.

Comment: Go to the url to edit your app with an additional querystring. Your final url should look something like : "https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/:id/edit?oauth2=enabled". Just make sure to replace :id with your app id.

Comment: Oh bizarre! Never seen an API like it. Thanks for your help.